# cxf get exception in websphere 8 unix platform

Tags: web-services, jaxb, cxf, websphere-8

I install cxf application into websphere  Platform 8.0.0.4  , the application throws  exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: mobileapp.cot.ca.data.WorkerData$JaxbAccessorF_sendBy cannot be cast to com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.OptimizedAccessorFactory.instanciate(OptimizedAccessorFactory.java:179)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.OptimizedAccessorFactory.get(OptimizedAccessorFactory.java:171)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.Accessor$FieldReflection.optimize(Accessor.java:245)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementLeafProperty.<init>(SingleElementLeafProperty.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor195.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:113)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:145)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:479)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:498)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.<init>(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor194.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

It's a problem for old jaxb version . my question is this cxf application doesn't have any jaxb jar files in lib forlder just used the default jaxb implementation , and it's works well in my local websphere (windows 8.0.0.5) ,why it can not work in unix platform . the other question which jar file is the jaxb implemention  in webspher. Thanks in advance.

the below is websphere platform information.

```
************ Start Display Current Environment ************
WebSphere Platform 8.0.0.5 [BASE 8.0.0.5 cf051243.01] running with process name J2X8Node01Cell\J2XD0095888Node01\server1 and process id 3528
Host Operating System is Windows 7, version 6.1
Java version = 1.6.0, Java Compiler = j9jit26, Java VM name = IBM J9 VM
was.install.root = C:\dev\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer
user.install.root = C:\dev\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01
Java Home = C:\dev\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\jre
ws.ext.dirs = C:\dev\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/java/lib;C:\dev\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01/classes;C:\dev\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/classes;C:\dev\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib;C:\dev\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/installedChannels;C:\dev\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/ext;C:\dev\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/web/help;C:\dev\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/deploytool/itp/plugins/com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy/runtime
Classpath = C:\dev\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01/properties;C:\dev\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/properties;C:\dev\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/startup.jar;C:\dev\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/bootstrap.jar;C:\dev\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/jsf-nls.jar;C:\dev\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/lmproxy.jar;C:\dev\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/urlprotocols.jar;C:\dev\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/deploytool/itp/batchboot.jar;C:\dev\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/deploytool/itp/batch2.jar;C:\dev\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/java/lib/tools.jar
Java Library path = C:\dev\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer/lib/native/win/x86_32/;C:\dev\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\jre\bin\default;C:\dev\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\jre\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\dev\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\lib\native\win\x86_32;C:\dev\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\bin;C:\dev\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\bin;C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\bin;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Novell\GroupWise;C:\Program Files\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui;C:\Program Files\Symantec\pcAnywhere\;C:\dev\IBM\RationalSDLC\ClearCase\bin;C:\dev\IBM\RationalSDLC\common;.;
Orb Version = IBM Java ORB build orb626ifx-20120304.00 (++191257)



************ Start Display Current Environment ************
WebSphere Platform 8.0.0.4 [ND 8.0.0.4 cf041228.02] running with process name haet-4Cell\hamlet-4Node1\WES-Admin-Intranet and process id 26915
Host Operating System is SunOS, version 5.10
Java version = 1.6.0_31, Java Compiler = HotSpot Client Compiler, Java VM name = Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
was.install.root = /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer
user.install.root = /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/hamlet-4AS1
Java Home = /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre
ws.ext.dirs = /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/lib:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/hamlet-4AS1/classes:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/classes:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/installedChannels:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/ext:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/web/help:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/deploytool/itp/plugins/com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy/runtime
Classpath = /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/hamlet-4AS1/properties:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/properties:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/startup.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/bootstrap.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/jsf-nls.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/lmproxy.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/urlprotocols.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/deploytool/itp/batchboot.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/deploytool/itp/batch2.jar:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/lib/tools.jar
Java Library path = /opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/lib/native/solaris/sparc_32/:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/sparc/server:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/lib/sparc:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/java/jre/../lib/sparc:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/bin:.:/usr/jdk/packages/lib/sparc:/lib:/usr/lib:
Orb Version = IBM Java ORB build orb626ifx-20120410.00 (SR2FP1+191257)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if helps, but double check JDK version on both environments. Same stack trace is when you're trying to run on a JDK7 WebSphere server a JAXB-based application compiled on JDK6.